# Converting numbers into German words

Tags: java

So my task is to convert numbers into German, and I am having a problem with "ein" and "eins".
Whenever I put in 101101 --> I get "einhunderteinstausendeinhunderteins" which is incorrect it is only the last ein in the number that needs to end with s --> "eins", but somehow I also have the eins in einstausend?
Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
public abstract class InGerman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = Terminal.getInt("Enter a number between 1 - 999999:  --->  ");
        Terminal.put("number in german: " + inGerman(number));
    }

    public static final String[] unitsArray = {" ", "eins", "zwei", "drei", "vier", "fünf", "sechs", "sieben", "acht",
            "neun", "zehn", "elf", "zölf", "dreizehn", "vierzehn", "fünfzehn", "sechszehn", "siebzehn", "achtzehn",
            "neunzehn"};
    public static final String[] tensArray = {" ", "zehn", "zwanzig", "dreissig", "vierzig", "fünfzig", "sechszig",
            "siebzig", "achtzig", "neunzig"};

    static int einer = 0;

    private static String inGerman(int number) {
        // variable to hold string representation of number
        String words = "";

        while (number == 0 || number == 1) {
            if (number == 0)
                return "null";
            if (number == 1) {
                return words + "ein";
            }
        }
        // check if number is divisible by 1 million
        if ((number / 1000000) > 0) {
            words += inGerman(number / 1000000) + "million" + "";
            number %= 1000000;
        }
        // check if number is divisible by 1 thousand
        if ((number / 1000) > 0) {
            words += inGerman(number / 1000) + "tausend";
            number %= 1000;

        }
        // check if number is divisible by 1 hundred
        if ((number / 100) > 0) {
            words += inGerman(number / 100) + "hundert";
            number %= 100;
        }

        if (number > 0) {
            // check if number is within teens
            if (number < 20) {
                // fetch the appropriate value from unit array
                words += unitsArray[number];
            } else {
                // fetch the appropriate value from tens array
                words += unitsArray[number % 10];
                if ((number % 10) > 0) {
                    words += "und" + tensArray[number / 10];
                }
            }
        }

        return words;
    }
}
```

Comment: To me it looks like you need to make an extra check so that you never call inGerman recursive with the value 1 (at least when dividing by larger numbers) but handle it directly.

Comment: `zölf` should be `zwölf`, `dreissig` should be `dreißig`, `sechszehn` should be `sechzehn`. Also its `eintausend` and `zweitausend`, but for millions, its `eine million vierhunderttausend` (singualr) and then `zwei millionen fünfhunderttausend` (plural in millionen). Same applies for Milliarde/milliarden, Billion/billionen etc.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not so bad except for the meaningless while statement and the unused `static int einer`.

You could include "null" und "ein" (not "eins") in the unitsArray and remove the while statement. Then change "inGerman" to a private method "internalInGerman", and handle the special cases 1 (and maybe 0? check it out for yourself) in a new public inGerman method, like so:

```
public String inGerman(int number) {
    return number == 1 ? "eins" : internalInGerman(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Joakim Danielson is right. You can't call `inGerman` recursively with the value `1` as the method can't tell where in the word the 'ein' or 'eins' is going to end up.

These lines can all result in the value `1` which will always pull `eins` from the `unitsArray`:

```
number %= 1000000;
number %= 1000;
number %= 100;
```

If you want to take the lazy approach, as I would, you can replace `eins` with `ein` in the `unitsArray` and then call this method on your String:

```
inGerman(number).replaceAll( "ein$", "eins");
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it in my inGerman method and not calling it in my:
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int number = Terminal.getInt("Enter a number between 1 - 999999:  --->  ");
  Terminal.put("number in german: " + inGerman(number).replaceAll( "ein$", "eins"));

Comment: If you really want to, you can do it like this:
return words.replaceAll("eins", "ein").replaceAll( "ein$", "eins" );

Comment: ahh of course makes sense to put it there, thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I did an implementation in php, but maybe you can get an idea about the logic.
It's also based on recursion. As others already pointed out, there are two special cases, `0` and `1`, where you can not call the recursion.
As polygnome pointed out, the higher numbers have a slightly different logic with singular and plural.

You can check out the code here https://github.com/Raphi1/number-to-words
The last (public) function is the entry point, you would call from the outside to get your string result.